# no such table when table does exist sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm having an issue where I get this error: `pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on SQL 'SELECT * FROM parent_reply WHERE unix > 0 AND parent NOT NULL AND score > 0 ORDER BY unix ASC LIMIT 5000': no such table: parent_reply` but there is actually a table called parent_reply. http://prntscr.com/l41j7p (That's the SQLite DB browser) Does anyone know what is causing this/how to fix it? I have checked multiple times, I am using the correct table names.

Comment: Beware, postgresql has a notion of *schema*. Maybe the application implicitely uses a different schema than the one that contains the table... (not speaking or user).

Comment: Are you certain the SQLite DB browser connects to the same database file that your app does ? If you get the path wrong, you will connect to a new but empty database. Please triple verify you are connecting to the correct database file. I also advice you to use the command line `sqlite3` application. Run it like `sqlite3 /path/to/your_dbfile.db`  , in there issue the command `.tables` to list the tables. Issue also the `.dump` command to view the full database dump, find the definition for the `parent_reply` table and verify it has not been named with any whitespace or unreadable characters.

Comment: It's very easy to instantly create databases if they don't exist, since `sqlite3.connect()` will simply spring a new database into life with no schema. This bites me more times than I'd like to admit, especially when jumping from running scripts to using the console and there is a mismatch of the current working directory. Check the schema of whatever connection you have active that's throwing the error and check you've not spawned a new, empty DB on some other path

Comment: @nos Your comment worked, so it should probably become an answer. Thanks so much!